# Golang - Socket server do not accept multiple client

Tags: go, sockets

I'm experimenting with creating a server socket that can accept multiple clients at the same time. But I have a problem handling the clients.
I checked and found that, after the server accepted 1 socket connection, it was not ready to accept further connections, even though I used **Goroutines**.
The incoming connection seems to hang, until it drops the connection. Only then can other client sockets connect

This is my socket server code

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}
defer l.Close()
for {
   conn, err := l.Accept()
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }

   go func(c net.Conn) {
      for {
         message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
         if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error: %+v", err.Error())
            return
         }

         log.Println("Message:", string(message))
      }
   }(conn)
}
```

Comment: You're reading from the wrong connection with `message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')` - you shouldn't be reading from `conn` but from `c`, or you should rename the argument `c` to `conn`  as in `go func(conn net.Conn) {`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks so much, but that problem is still not solved :(

Comment: You don't want to recreate a `bufio.Reader` for every message you receive. Instead you should have created a single reader and loop-reading from that.

Comment: @iBug I tried putting reader := bufio.NewReader(conn) out for {}, but everything is the same

Comment: If you follow the suggestions above everything works fine. https://go.dev/play/p/SaUaHe0XwZP

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found the problem was that my Client was not sending the last byte as '\n'. So the server couldn't read the []byte that the client sent.
I just learned to use golang socket and found it quite different from C# or Java. In C#, when the client BinaryWriter.Flush() then on the server BinaryReader will receive all the bytes written in the writer, but in golang that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm not sure about this, can someone explain it to me

Comment: I finally have a solution, I create a byte array of the desired length = size and read the data from the client.